# Access an object node with a variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, object

I've a jQuery object (counts) like this :

```
Object {men: 299, womens: 175, children: 173}
```

I just want to retrieve the value to display it in a span (the data-filter attributes are the same as the object keys)

```
$( "a.type_select" ).each(function() {
    var theType = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    var theCounter = counts.theType;
    $(this).children('span.count').html(' ('+theCounter+')');
});
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counts.theType` access the key `theType` of the object `counts`.

It is important to know that object key can also be accessed by string. You just need to use bracket. for example :

```
counts['men']; // 299
```

That being said, you can pass a variable to the bracket :

```
counts[theType]
```

That will return what you want.